# Passing a Variable To A Jquery Function

Tags: jquery, variables, iteration

I have a list of items that I'd like to perform the same action on. They all have separate IDs so I want to be able to pass the name of each one to Jquery so that the action is only performed on that ID.
For example:

```
<a href="#" id="1">one</a>
<a href="#" id="2">two</a>
<div id="#test1"></div>
<div id="#test2"></div>
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
function doSomething(x) {
     var div=x+'div';
     $(x).click(function() { $.(div).slideDown(); });
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: `id="#foo"` is illegal. You can't have `#` in the `id`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <a href="#" class="x" d="test1">one</a>
> <a href="#" class="x" d="test2">two</a>
> <div id="test1" class="x"></div>
> <div id="test2" class="x"></div>
> ```

```
function doSomething(x) 
{
   $("a.x").click(function()
   { $( "div#" + $(this).attr("d") ).slideDown(); }
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onclick` attribute, that simplifies the code a bit:

```
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="handleClick(this)">one</a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="handleClick(this)">two</a>
<div id="#test1"></div>
<div id="#test2"></div>

function handleClick(x) {
     $('#test'+ x.id).slideDown();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass jQuery element/s directly into the function like so:

```
var doSomething = function(el){
    el.click(function(){ });
};

// Single element
var $el = $('a.class');
doSomething($el);

// Multiple elements
var $elms = $('a.class, a#id');
doSomething($elms);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to pass variable in jquery fn

```
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#but").click(function() {
                var n = $(this).attr("n");
                alert(n);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="but" href="#" n="I Love You">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` attributes like this to store the data along with html elements and retrieve them using jQuery `data()` method. Try this.

Html change

```
<a href="#" data-id="1">one</a>
<a href="#" data-id="2">two</a>
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

Use this js

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('#test' + $(this).data('id')).slideDown();
});
```

To retrieve the data attribute value using jQuery `data` method just pass the second half of the attribute. So in this case passing `id` to `data` will give us the id value.